How to get a grip to a distorted oil filter
I damaged an oil filter by mistakenly rotating it to the wrong direction (I was stupid. My brain messed up at that time). Now The oil filter is distorted and normal oil filter wrench cannot get a grip. Any suggestions to get a grip to that distorted air filter to  remove it? Thank you!
![damaged oil filter] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vCcnKatXMcFUvzyswFlqB7qmauHUPBtS/view?usp=sharing)

This question is similar to: Oil filter on my motorcycle is not coming off. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MTA thanks for the reference. I will try out those methods and let the forum know how it goes.
